# Comparison operations on xs:boolean in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, xquery, xquery-sql

Can anyone explain to me the results of this query:

```
declare @xml xml;
set @xml = '<node attribute="true">Val</node>';

select
    T.c.query('xs:boolean(@attribute[1])') Value,
    T.c.query('xs:boolean(@attribute[1]) = false') ValueEqualsFalse,
    T.c.query('xs:boolean(@attribute[1]) = true') ValueEqualsTrue,
    T.c.query('xs:boolean(@attribute[1]) != false') ValueNotEqualsFalse,
    T.c.query('xs:boolean(@attribute[1]) != true') ValueNotEqualsTrue
from @Xml.nodes('node') T(c);
```

The first column, Value, returns true.  The rest all return false.  So having managed to cast the value to the correct type, how do I actually check it's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `fn:false()` or `false()` and `fn:true()` or `true()` instead of just writing `true` or `false`.

**This is a correct example:**

```
T.c.query('xs:boolean(@attribute[1]) = false()') ValueEqualsFalse,
T.c.query('xs:boolean(@attribute[1]) = true()') ValueEqualsTrue,
T.c.query('xs:boolean(@attribute[1]) != false()') ValueNotEqualsFalse,
T.c.query('xs:boolean(@attribute[1]) != true()') ValueNotEqualsTrue
```

If you don't use the function `false()`, `false` is processed as a path expression, i.e. the processor thinks you are querying for a `<false />` element. Therefore, there only exists a function for the constants `true` and `false`, because this is the only way to distinguish between the boolean constants and a path expression.

More in detail, using the negation would still return `false` in each example.

**This is not what you want (just to demonstrate):**

```
T.c.query('not(xs:boolean(@attribute[1])) = false') ValueEqualsFalse,
T.c.query('not(xs:boolean(@attribute[1])) = true') ValueEqualsTrue,
T.c.query('not(xs:boolean(@attribute[1])) != false') ValueNotEqualsFalse,
T.c.query('not(xs:boolean(@attribute[1])) != true') ValueNotEqualsTrue
```

the literals `false` and `true` both are evaluated to an empty sequence which neither matches the boolean value `false()` nor the boolean value `true()`.

Comment: The empty sequence is not cast to `false` in the latter case.  Instead you are comparing a boolean value with an empty sequence.  The `=` and `!=` operators are sequence comparisons, and return true if there is a pair of items in the input sequences that satisfies the comparison.  Since there are no items in the empty sequence that satisfy the comparison, the result of all these cases is false().